# create folder in python

Tags: python, html, mechanize, lxml

How can I make this script grab the "nmv-fas" from the link name and create a directory with that name then place all the files that are downloaded in that directory.

all.html:

```
<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.45.nmv-fas">http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.45.nmv-fas</a>
<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.46.nmv-fas">http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.46.nmv-fas</a>
<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.47.nmv-fas">http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.47.nmv-fas</a>
<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.48.nmv-fas">http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.48.nmv-fas</a>
<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.49.nmv-fas">http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.49.nmv-fas</a>
<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.50.nmv-fas">http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.50.nmv-fas</a>
<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/exod.1.nmv-fas">http://www.youversion.com/bible/exod.1.nmv-fas</a>
<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/exod.2.nmv-fas">http://www.youversion.com/bible/exod.2.nmv-fas</a>
<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/exod.3.nmv-fas">http://www.youversion.com/bible/exod.3.nmv-fas</a>
```

files saved in folder named:

```
nmv-fas
```

python:

```
import lxml.html as html
import urllib
import urlparse
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

root = html.parse(open('all.html'))
for link in root.findall('//a'):
  url = link.get('href')
  name = urlparse.urlparse(url).path.split('/')[-1]
  f = urllib.urlopen(url)
  s = f.read()
  f.close()
  soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
  articleTag = soup.html.body.article
  converted = str(articleTag)
  open(name, 'w').write(converted)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `lxml` module to parse links out of the file, and then use `urllib` to download each link.  Reading the links might look like this:

```
import lxml.html as html

root = html.parse(open('links.html'))
for link in root.findall('//a'):
  url = link.get('href')
```

You can download a link to a file using `urllib.urlopen`:

```
import urllib
import urlparse

# extract the final path component and use it as
# the local filename.
name = urlparse.urlparse(url).path.split('/')[-1]

fd = urllib.urlopen(url)
open(name, 'w').write(fd.read())
```

Put these together and you should have something similar to what you want.

Comment: that works very well except it only downloads the very last link, not all of them

Comment: Oh no, if you put them together correctly it works just fine.  You're just copying and pasting without thinking.  Maybe you need to put something *inside the loop*.

Comment: nevermind I figured it out. I didnt realize how strict python was when it came to formatting and syntax.

Comment: Awesome.  If this answer helped you out, consider marking it "accepted" by checking the checkmark to the left of the question.  Cheers!